# Any HTML to PDF renderers that offer adjustable dpi, selectable text, and CSS support?

Tags: javascript, php, c++, pdf, pdf-generation

I am building a specification sheet for a client with Vue and need to make viewable and printable PDFs.

I've was dabbling with Puppeteer, but from what I've came across online (correct me if I'm wrong), Puppeteer does not support selectable text nor adjusting the DPI of PDFs.  I am also having an issue where Puppeteer renders the PDF in low quality - where the font is fuzzy/without anti-aliasing.

What (if any) PDF renderers are there that will

- render an HTML page to PDF*
- support selectable text*
- allow for adjustable DPI*
- CSS Support* (i.e. it will render the CSS)
- can accept URL as parameter
- allow for multiple pages
- and runs in Node/Javascript (optional)

Edit: The best I've found so far was with [eKoopmans html2pdf](https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf), but unfortunately, it doesn't allow for selectable text (as far as I can tell) - which is a deal breaker.

There doesn't seem to be such a package for javascript, so if there is one in PHP or C++ - it will also be considered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution I've found is [ebdrup/html2pdf.it](https://github.com/ebdrup/html2pdf.it).  You can find a live demo [here](http://www.html2pdf.it/).  It makes use of Phantom JS and would seem to support every feature I need, with the exception of page breaks which I haven't tested yet.

The next hurdle is to figure out how to extract the necessary functions so I can use the features in my script without having to pass GET query strings (which deserves it's own question).

Edit: An issue I didn't realize is there doesn't seem to be a way to delay the PDF generation, which is an issue since I am using Vue and the page has to build first.

## Edit 2020:

Since this post, I've revisited Puppeteer and it handles everything that I need.

### Adjust DPI

You can adjust the DPI by setting the page viewport.

Puppeteer equates [1in = 96px](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/bb1c5215a8ef7238be2ef25a17b97ac708ccf994/src/common/Page.ts).  ctrl+f for `unitToPixels`

Example.

```js
const browser = puppeteer.launch();

const page = await browser.newPage();

// Multiply the desired length in inches by 96
await page.setViewport({ 
   width: 8.5 * 96,
   height: 11 * 96,
});
```

### Wait for...

You can wait for a selector before finishing.  In my case, I append a class to the body for Puppeteer to listen and capture.

```js
const browser = puppeteer.launch();

const page = await browser.newPage();

const html = buildDOM();  // Has js that appends .finished class to <body>

await page.setContent(html);

await page.waitForSelector('.finished');
```

Comment: did you make a selectable text pdf with that libray? how? I can't find so much info there

Comment: @Tupac Recently I've used Puppeteer.  It's possible I was mistaken when I first wrote this 2 years ago, but Puppeteer now does support selectable text and adjustable DPI.